# Missing argument for parameter 'OnChildWithName' in call when using SKAction

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit

hoping to get some quick help.

I am making an app that lives in the status bar on OS X and I'm trying to call a function every 5 seconds which prints `"YEP"` using the following `SKAction`.

```
    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)

    let checkIt = SKAction.runBlock {
        println("YEP")
    }
    let action = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, checkIt])
    SKAction.runAction(action) //error here
```

Could anyone please help me out with this error? It occurs at the line

```
SKAction.runAction(action)
```

Comment: If you're just using SpriteKit because you want to run some code every few seconds, then SpriteKit is probably overkill.  Have you tried `NSTimer`?

Comment: I have looked at using an NSTimer but I have found it hard to get it working properly. I could put all my code in a function that is called every 5 seconds with an NSTimer but I can't get the timer working properly.

Comment: And now you're not getting `SKAction` working properly.  Sounds like you're stuck between a rock and a hard place, except in this case, one of them (`NSTimer`) is the right path, and the other (`SKAction`) is the wrong path.

Comment: Okay cool, i'll ditch the SKAction and go for the NSTimer. Thanks

Comment: Got it, way less complicated than I thought @nhgrif thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method called `runAction` on the `SKAction` class.

The method is `runAction(_:onChildWithName:)`.

You must pass both the `SKAction` you wish to perform as well as the `String` which represents the name of the child you wish to run the action on.

```
SKAction.runAction(action onChildWithName: "NameOfChild")
```

Comment: Okay awesome thanks! I can't figure out what the child I wish to run the action on is. It's in the class AppDelegate and in the function applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: See the comment I left on your question.  You probably don't need to use SpriteKit...